# How to set selected option?

Tags: angularjs

Here is the problem, I create table with `ng-repeat`, in table td I have select with option, I need to set selected option.

```
 <tr id="edit" ng-repeat="x in products">
     <td style="width: 2%;display: none;">{{x.id}}</td>
     <td style="width: 16%"><h6 style="font-weight: normal;" ng-bind="nameResult"  ng-hide="false"></h6>
       <select style="margin: -16px 0 0 0;" class="span12" style="margin: 0;" ng-change="loadProductData(x)" id="product_list" ng-options="prod.product_name as prod.product_name for prod in items track by prod.product_id" ng-model="selectedOption">    
           <option value="">Select product</option>
           <option label="Registracija korisni" value="57">Registracija korisni</option>
           <option selected="selected" label="Testing of platform" value="58">Testing of platform</option>
           <option label="Test 2" value="63">Test 2</option>
           <option label="irfam" value="87">irfam</option>
           <option label="ddd" value="88">ddd</option>
      </select>
     </td>
 <tr>
```

So I have multiple select with same `ng-model` how to set selected different option for each select.

Comment: you can try : ng-model="x.selectedOption"

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: ok, so I have couple select whit same ng-model="x.selectedOption", how to select prefered option for each select

Comment: May this example can be helpful for you. http://jsbin.com/vojelajeda/edit?html,js,output

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/cypym9WEka4ERO8rbQqk/preview

Comment: Lai32290 my question is how to set selected not how to select manual and hold that value

Answer (score 1):

Since your `ng-model="selectedOption"` then angular will select the option which matches `selectedOption`. Since you are tracking by `prod.product_id` then `selectedOption` will need to be set to a `prod.product_id`.

I see you have set some options manually. If these are not being selected properly you may need to add these items to your `prod` object, then let angular create the options for you.

Comment: this is just for preview, course I create option in repeat, can you explain me whats mean "Since you are tracking by prod.product_id then selectedOption will need to be set to a prod.product_id."

Comment: Can you send me some code? How to set prefered value selected for each select

Comment: There are a lot of examples at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: selectedOption is your model data. Angularjs will select the option defined in the track by expression. In this case track by is prod.product_id. Therefore angular will select the option who's value matches selectedOption.

Comment: thank you man you solve my problem. Miles P